# How to make a React dropdown to render the array the user clicks on AND show "nothing found here!" if array is empty?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to figure out a better way to render the array of objects of this Dropdown.
I can currently see all arrays correctly but, for example, if captured or released arrays are empty, I get an empty screen. I tried setting up the ternary operator such as "value === capturedPkm && capturedPkm === '' ? Nothing found here : capturedPkm.map() but then I would need another : to show 'released' or 'all' and that's not how the ternary operator works. How can I make it so to show Nothing to be found here if the array are empty AND show another component when the user clicks on it? I hope I made myself clear enough. If not, please tell me so!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";

const Dropdown = ({
  pokemons,
  capturedPkm,
  releasedPkm,
  setCapturedPkm,
  setReleasedPkm,
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([pokemons]);
  const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
  return (
    <div className="select">
      <select name={JSON.stringify(value)} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value={JSON.stringify(pokemons)}>All</option>
        <option value={JSON.stringify(capturedPkm)}>Captured</option>
        <option value={JSON.stringify(releasedPkm)}>Released</option>
      </select>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        }}
      >
        {value === JSON.stringify(capturedPkm)
          ? capturedPkm.map((el, i) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <img src={el.img} alt={"pokemon"} />
                  {el.name}
                </div>
              );
            })
          : value === JSON.stringify(releasedPkm)
          ? releasedPkm.map((el, i) => {
              return <div>{el.name}</div>;
            })
          : pokemons.map((pokemon, index) => {
              return (
                <div style={{ width: "235px" }} key={index}>
                  <PokemonCard
                    pokemon={pokemon}
                    index={index}
                    name={pokemon.name}
                    capturedPkm={capturedPkm}
                    setCapturedPkm={setCapturedPkm}
                    notCapturedPkm={releasedPkm}
                    setNotCapturedPkm={setReleasedPkm}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this turns out to be useful for anybody, I've just added a new condition in case of empty array, and it works perfectly. I will upload my own question (LOL) with edited and refactored code.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to reflect your answer! IF need be, post your answer to your own question, but do not edit your question that shows an answer.

Comment: Ok? I just thought it could be useful! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it could certainly be useful.  We just do not want a question to be updated to (also) reflect the answer.  Question should be a (only) a question and not include the answer.  You can post an answer to your own question.  YOu can do  so with the "edited and refactored code"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it definitely makes sense!